# autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, autorelease

I am currently receiving the error :

```
2000-01-03 06:51:27.-641 mytestapp[470:5c03
] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x15a5a0 
of class __NSArrayM >autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

From investigation of the other stackoverflow links, this problem seems to occur when people do not create an autorelease pool before a thread selector and drain it after.

However, I have attempted to accommodate this and still am stumped.
I have the code here on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/91Y9GLwu). If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"create an autorelease pool before a thread selector and drain it after" What? where have you heard this?

You must have understood it wrong. You don't put an autorelease pool on the original thread -- that's useless. You are supposed to put it in the new thread, just around all the code that will execute in the thread. In your case, that means inside the block -- create it at the beginning of the body of the block, and drain it at the end of the body of the block.

Comment: Thank You. Yes I am an iOS newbie so I misunderstood. Following your advice my attempt at correcting this involved placing the autorelease pool at the top of the block of code (before if (error)) and draining the pool at the end of the block (after accelerometerLabel performSelectorOnMainThread:). However, this has not resolved the problem? Am I doing it correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need an autoreleasepool in place in the main.m, else any object that attempts to recieve the autorelease message will "just leak" with no pool in place.  Unfortunately, that mutable array is probably a framework object, so your pool would do nothing to fix it.

Comment: Thanks CodaFi, When I run the code on my iPhone 4S and iPAD ( both on iOS5) the code doesn't produce this error. Any Ideas?

Comment: You got lucky.  Cocoa-touch expects autoreleasepools on background threads.

Comment: I see, thanks. Can your advice on the fix suggested in the above comment?